# Resizing a Visio shape through Visual Basic

Tags: vba, resize, visio

So I've been working on trying to resize a Visio box in Visual Basic for a project in work, using some code that was given to me as I am very new to Visual Basic. 
I have tried many methods without any result, and I am now working on using the Shape.Resize() method which works but then throws an error:

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "D" Then
        Dim sizer As Double
        sizer# = 2
        iData = iData + 1
        Set shp = CreateVisioObject(AppVisio, "Box", 2.5, 7.25, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, """AccentColor4""")
        Set shp = shp.Resize(0, sizer, 65)
        Set shp = shp.Resize(2, sizer, 65)
    End If
```

On line 6, I get the error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch", but the code still executes before throwing this error (ie; the width of the shape changes but the code stops at this line.) Here is the code for the CreateVisioObject:

```
Function CreateVisioObject(ByRef oVisio As Object, strType As String, posX As Double, posY As Double, strText As String, strColor As String) As Object
Set shp = oVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(oVisio.Documents.Item("BLOCK_U.VSS").Masters.ItemU(strType), posX, posY)
shp.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "20 pt"


Set oCharacters = shp.Characters
oCharacters.Begin = 0
oCharacters.End = Len(oCharacters)
sChar = strText
oCharacters.Text = sChar



shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(THEMEVAL(" + strColor + "))"
shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillBkgnd).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(SHADE(FillForegnd,LUMDIFF(THEMEVAL(""FillColor""),THEMEVAL(""FillColor2""))))"
shp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowGradientProperties, visFillGradientEnabled).FormulaU = "FALSE"


Set CreateVisioObject = shp
End Function
```

Here is the reference for the Shape.Resize() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/shape-resize-method-visio

Also, the code is using an Excel sheet to generate the Visio document.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know about **Shape.Resize Method** before. When i want resize some shape i just change it **Width** and **Height**

```
   shp.Cells("width") = 2
   shp.Cells("height") = 2
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help!